# DBeaver BigQuery Table with JSON Error "The specified column type is currently unsupported by the driver for column JSON."

Tags: json, google-bigquery, database-connection, dbeaver

I am able to connect to BigQuery and read non JSON fields of a table.But when I read the JSON field I get the below error.
I am using community edition DataGrip version 2022.3.3 (Build #DB-223.8617.3, built on January 10, 2023).

<sub>SQL Error [100064] [HY000]: [Simba]BigQueryJDBCDriver The specified column type is currently unsupported by the driver for column JSON.</sub>

I know this is related to the Bigquery driver version, which i have updated and yet the error persists.

Hoping someone has faced this error before and solved it.

Comment: Which version of the Simba driver are you using?

Comment: I am using SimbaJDBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery42_1.2.21.1025